# what does "put something in caps and sparkles" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from [Crash Course Biology](https://youtu.be/HVT3Y3_gHGg). It is at around 2 minute and 44 second. Here is the context:

> Seriously though, I can't overstate the importance of this hydrogen bond. So when your teacher asks you, "What is important about water?" Start out with the hydrogen bond and you should put it in **all caps** and maybe some **sparkles** around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He suggests, *"all caps"* (meaning using all capital letters) to emphasize the importance. Pretty straight forward.

He adds, *"and maybe some sparkles around it"* as a light sort of joke because in the beginning of the video, he talks about the Hydrogen Bond as being **magical**.

At 0:18 he really emphasizes this in his introduction "And to celebrate this **MAGICAL** bond..."

So imagine writing it in all caps with sparkles around it:

[image]

And we think of sparkles as showing something magical! It's an entertaining science show so he often adds light jokes like this that you can enjoy or just ignore, but either way you shouldn't take it seriously.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a way of saying that you should ***!!EMPHASIZE!!*** it so it really stands out. (Because it's so important.)

Of course, you can't *really* emphasize the hydrogen bond in that way, so "all caps" and "sparkles" are being used figuratively.

Comment: I found myself wondering if _sparkles_ means "asterisks" (or "stars") in this context; ergo: `The important thing about water is the **HYDROGEN BOND**`